# VS Code Python Preview error Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

У меня свежеустановленный Linux Mint XFCE Ulyana, при попытке запустить Python Preview (Дополнение) получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'

При этом, сам интерпретатор, виртуальное окружение, дебагер в vs code работают нормально. Гугл подсказывает только про Windows 10 и про MacOS.

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну наверное выкосили вторую версию, оставив только третью. Попробуйте символическую ссылку добавить, если действительно в этом проблема.

Comment: Пробовал и символическую ссылку кидать(временную правда). Сам python2.7 в системе есть но тоже не "сидит" на python. А какой версии python нужен данному расширению не подскажите?